# How to communicate via modbus RTU on android through micro USB port?

Tags: android, usb, modbus

For the project i am working on i have a slave device that communicates using modbus protocol.  All i need to do is be able to read the holding registers on the device via modbus RTU.  The device has an RS485 output.  I have already purchased an RS485 to usb converter cable that include an FTDI chip.  And also a usb to micro usb cable to connect that to the tablet.  So far i have been able to write a simple java program in netbeans to connect through the usb port on my laptop and read data from the holding registers on the device.  So i do not have a problem with communicating with modbus.

The problem i am having is with sending the modbus communication through the micro usb port.  My tablet is set up as a host, and i have been able to recognize that a device is attached.  I am also able to connect to the port that the device is attached to. Im just getting very confused on how to use the micro usb protocol to send modbus communication over. The code i have for modbus on my laptop just needs a port number to communicate through, but i dont think it is that simple with an android tablet. I have been going through this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html and understand for the most part what is going on, but i cant figure out how to use this information to send modbus communication over.  any help would be great!

Comment: You need to find or create code which talks to the FTDI chip using raw USB operations against the Android USB host API, and then you need to do your modbus-specific software protocol on top of that.

Comment: Thank you, and yes that does make sense.  I have been able to find code that talks to the ftdi chip but the part im getting confused about is how to use the modbus specific protocol on top of that. I guess i am just stuck on how to build the modbus code on top of the usb operations.

Comment: Try to create a layer on top of the FTDI-aware USB code which provides something like the serial API which I presume your laptop implementation is built on top of - ie, implement read() and write() functions and (where it gets tricky) whatever is used to control the transmit enable (likely done through re-purposing of a handshake signal).

Comment: oh ok, i have some learning to do ahead of me, this is my first time writing code for communication through usb.  All i have worked on up to this point is modbus TCP over IP.  And the code i used for my laptop is a package that i downloaded. So i am going to have to dig into their code and figure out how they are doing it so i can re-work it to work with the usb code?

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have been stuck on this for a couple weeks now and have not been able to find very much information online.  At least i know i was on the right path now and what steps i need to take.

Comment: Did you come out with any solution? I'm working on that right now